# how to get visual c++ default include path using cmake?

Tags: cmake

I try to use cmake determine whether exist inttypes.h header file for generate project of visual c++ 11.

Initially, i wrote the following sentence in CMakeLists.txt

```
FIND_FILE(HAVE_INTTYPES_H "inttypes.h" DOC "Does the inttypes.h exist?")
```

Unfortunately， the HAVE_INTTYPES_H variable is HAVE_INTTYPES_H-NOTFOUND.

Afterwards, i looked up cmake documentation about find_file, which mentioned the need to some search path. But i can not get the c standard header files in any place in cmake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `find_file` call is correct. The problem is there's no inttypes.h on Visual Studio. So keep your test the same, but when it's not found include another headers, for instance provided by: http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/

Something like:

```
FIND_FILE(HAVE_INTTYPES_H "inttypes.h" DOC "Does the inttypes.h exist?")
if (HAVE_INTTYPES_H)
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1)
endif()
```

and in your code:

```
#ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
#include <inttypes.h>
#else
#include "path/to/inttypes.h"
#endif
```

Now, to detect headers, you may also want to try using the `CheckIncludeFile` standard CMake module, it's trying to detect include files using your target compiler instead of searching the file system:

```
include(CheckIncludeFile)

check_include_file("stdint.h" STDINT_H_FOUND)
if (STDINT_H_FOUND)
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_STDINT_H=1)
endif()
```

Comment: Thanks, but i find stdint.h still fails at visual studio 2012. However, this document does exist, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdint.h"

Comment: I edited my post to include another way of detecting headers with check_include_file, that might works better for you.